# Stylizing textarea to look like separate input box's

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, textarea

I designed a text area so that it looks like three separate text input box's. For styling purposes there needs to be a black line separating each line of text.

However, I can't figure out how to align the text so they feel centered in their individual sections. Can anyone lend a hand?

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rY9um/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="formPage">
   <div id="formBox">
      <div class="formSection" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <div class="formLine" style="height:49px;position:relative;">
          <div class="indent">This is a needed label that I put over the textarea that describes what people are filling out.</div>
          <div class="whiteIndent"></div>
          <div class="borderIndent"></div>
          <div class="whiteIndent2"></div>
          <div class="borderIndent2"></div>
          <textarea name="text1" class="indent" rows="3" maxlength="360"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { }
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

#formPage {
  font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  width:910px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:30px;
  height:100px;
 }

.formLine > textarea.indent { 
   position:absolute;
   font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size:13px;
   background-color:#E2F4FE;
   width:818px;
   z-index:0;
   top:0px;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;
   border:0;
   resize:none;
   overflow:hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .formLine > div.indent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;background-color:#fff;padding:2px 2px 2px 1px; }
  .formLine > div.whiteIndent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:16px;width:820px;height:3px;background-color:#fff; }
  .formLine > div.borderIndent { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:17px;left:0;border-top:1px solid #000;width:823px;height:1px; }
  .formLine > div.whiteIndent2 { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:32px;width:820px;height:3px;background-color:#fff; }
  .formLine > div.borderIndent2 { position:absolute;z-index:2;top:33px;left:0;border-top:1px solid #000;width:823px;height:1px; }

  .formSection { float:left;width:825px;border-right:2px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:13px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what *exactly* you're looking for. Do you still want the white bits? If you elaborate a bit more I can modify my answer accordingly. Here's a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/rY9um/1/

```
.formLine > textarea.indent { 
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.formLine > div.indent { 
  /* remove padding:2px 2px 2px 1px; from css - you can use line-height to achieve the same effect and consistency */
  line-height: 17px; 
  }
```

Set `line-height` to the height you want each row of text to take up. That allows you to set a small font size (13px), while making the line of text still take up 17px in height.

(On a slightly unrelated note, cleaning up your CSS and using better naming conventions would help you understand it better. For  example, it's not really necessary to be calling the textarea by `.formLine > textarea.indent`. You could simply give it a class `.textarea-indent` and call it by that. See [Writing Efficient CSS Selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/))

Comment: I still want the white bits because I'd like it to look like separate text input box's. Basically I want the text vertically centered in their separated blue lines. This seems to work nicely on the first and last line but stuff starts to get cut off on the second line now. Thanks for the help! and the suggestions for cleaning my CSS. I'm still learning.

Comment: Could this be similar to what you're looking for? :) With this, all you really need is to apply the CSS to only the textarea. http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-notebook-paper

Comment: My jsfiddle is exactly what I am looking for, just with the text more vertically centered. I think in my case, I am going to have to use a `textarea`. It's a specific style I dumbed down for simplicity.

Comment: I can't seem to get the line-height to work so that each line is evenly centered :|